# How do I keep my app from calling onCreate() when switching tabs?

Tags: android

I have an app that has a tabLayout. One of the Tabs does an HttpPost every time the tabs are switched. I would like the app to only load this info the first time and not call onCreate repeatedly. Is this possible?

edit: 
      OK, well I got it working by changing the way I set up the tabs it involved creating the intents a little differently, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Put your HTTPPost Code in a separate Method.
Then Override `onTabChanged` in you TabHost-Class and do something like that:

> String tabTag = getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag();
>       Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag);

```
if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ActivityName")) {
    MyActivity mActivity = (MyActivity) activity;
    infoActivity.methodToCallHTTPpost();
```

This code executes the `methodToCallHTTPpost` every time you switch to the Tab.
No simply change the if so that it will just be executed when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can take a better approach to your app with what info you have revealed.  Familiarize yourself with the lifecycle of an activity if you haven't already: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

As you can see, you have little control over when onCreate will be called.

What you can do though, is save the activity's state, and decide when HTTPpost should be called or not based on your saved information.